# position: sticky scroll still moving element

Tags: html, css

I have a requirement of displaying something similar to a table with a sticking first column that can scroll horizontally.

The column is being sticky for a while but when you scroll too much it starts moving with the rest:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.header-container, .row-data {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.header, .data {
  flex: 0 0 80px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.fullname {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="header-container">
      <div class="header fullname">Full Name</div>
      <div class="header">Test 1</div>
      <div class="header">Test 2</div>
      <div class="header">Test 3</div>
      <div class="header">Test 4</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="data-container">
      <div class="row-data">
        <div class="data fullname">Full Name</div>
        <div class="data">Test 1</div>
        <div class="data">Test 2</div>
        <div class="data">Test 3</div>
        <div class="data">Test 4</div>
      </div>

      <div class="row-data">
        <div class="data fullname">Full Name</div>
        <div class="data">Test 1</div>
        <div class="data">Test 2</div>
        <div class="data">Test 3</div>
        <div class="data">Test 4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I get that first Full Name column to be stickied without using a `<table>`  which brings it's own baggage of issues.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem seems to be with `row-data`, the width is not up to the end of the row which is affecting the behavior of sticky element. Basically `fullname` stops being "stuck" because it's parent width.

As per documentation:

> A stickily positioned element is an element whose computed position
>   value is sticky. It's treated as relatively positioned until its
>   containing block crosses a specified threshold (such as setting top to
>   value other than auto) within its flow root (or the container it
>   scrolls within), at which point **it is treated as "stuck" until
>   meeting the opposite edge of its containing block.**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Add this to understand better:

```
.row-data {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

The issue is `header-container` and `data-container` are getting width: 250px from the `wrapper` parent.

My solution would be to add a new `wrapper2` element which will have a fixed width like so:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.wrapper2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
}

.header-container, .row-data {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.header, .data {
  flex: 0 0 80px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.fullname {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background-color: orange;
}
.row-data {
  border:1px solid red;
}
.header-container {
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper2">

    <div class="header-container">
      <div class="header fullname">Full Name 1a</div>
      <div class="header">Test 1a</div>
      <div class="header">Test 2a</div>
      <div class="header">Test 3a</div>
      <div class="header">Test 4a</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="data-container">
      <div class="row-data">
        <div class="data fullname">Full Name 2b</div>
        <div class="data">Test 1b</div>
        <div class="data">Test 2b</div>
        <div class="data">Test 3b</div>
        <div class="data">Test 4b</div>
      </div>

      <div class="row-data">
        <div class="data fullname">Full Name 3c</div>
        <div class="data">Test 1c</div>
        <div class="data">Test 2c</div>
        <div class="data">Test 3c</div>
        <div class="data">Test 4c</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see it in action https://jsfiddle.net/noke7jc5/18/also here

Answer (score 3):

As described by August, I think position sticky isn't the best solution for your problem.

I made a similar approach using absolute positioning. placing your headlines before your rows using a pseudo element and data-attributes.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  padding-left: 120px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: orange;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}

.header-container,
.row-data {
  display: flex;
}

.header, .data {
  flex: 0 0 80px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.header-container::before,
.row-data::before{
  content: attr(data-title);
  left: 0px;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="header-container" data-title="Fullname">
        <div class="header">Test 1</div>
        <div class="header">Test 2</div>
        <div class="header">Test 3</div>
        <div class="header">Test 4</div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="data-container">
        <div class="row-data" data-title="Fullname">
          <div class="data">Test 1</div>
          <div class="data">Test 2</div>
          <div class="data">Test 3</div>
          <div class="data">Test 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-data" data-title="Fullname">
          <div class="data">Test 1</div>
          <div class="data">Test 2</div>
          <div class="data">Test 3</div>
          <div class="data">Test 4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this solution, unfortunately probably can't use it as the rows also have an edit mode that shows a dropdown in each cell. But It's a neat solution I'm going to keep in mind. I did find the solution to the problem I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue... when using sticky, you need to specify a width to your container.

In my case once I specified a width for .row-data and .header-container by adding up all the columns' widths it worked just fine.

Comment: This is similar to what I posted in my answer also.