# Position fixed (so that element sits outside of containing clipping area) but scrolled

Tags: css, position, overflow, fixed, absolute

I'm trying to have an element with a fixed position (so it'll not be clipped by it's containing element) but that will scroll by the viewport scroller...

[image]

as opposed to:

[image]

but that will scroll with the vertical viewport scroller.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: See if this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50954630/position-sticky-scroll-still-moving-element/50954998#50954998

Comment: absolutely not.
sticky keeps it inside its container and it takes space in the layout.
the goal is to achieve something like "fixed" (which hovers outside everything) but that scrolls